# Can a user mode program access the kernel memory and the memory of other processes?

Tags: linux, kernel

I have read in many tutorials that a user mode program cannot access the kernel memory and the memory of other processes.

But is this always true?

For example: couldn't the kernel map the kernel memory or the memory of some other process to the virtual address space of some process?

Answer (score 2):

You can read kernel address by reading the file `/dev/mem`.

You need to be root and the Linux kernel need to be compiled with `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=n` (many distributions enable `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` by default for security)

You can try this GitHub project I wrote: [link](https://github.com/lxylxy123456/ECS150Demo#page2frame)

Answer (score 0):

At least one prog I use takes advantage of using kernel space, netsniff-ng. Netsniff-ng is a zero-copy mechanism for capturing frames. It takes advantage by mapping the kernel space to user space.  Specifically using the SOCKET_MMAP syscall.  The results are fantastic.  I have used to capture frames on a switch port running 2.1 Gbps with zero dropped frames.

Click [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt) to see how the SOCKET_MMAP syscall functions and it may give you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

To access memory of other processes, you need capabilities that **normal** users do not have. However if you gain these capabilities, e.g. by becoming root, then you can do it.